# why the exception will throw even the syntax of code is correct?

Tags: exception

I have come across exceptions many times especially checked exceptions.When the syntax of the code is correct why should we have to put in try-catch block.
if we don't put into try-catch block it will give error.
please explain me about checked exceptions.why would some code will throw exceptions even the syntax is correct.

Comment: Btw exceptions have nothing to do with syntax errors. If there are syntax errors a code will not even compile. Exceptions happen at runtime.

Comment: But zenith why exception throws if every thing is fine.

Comment: Exceptions may be thrown if an error occurs when the program is run.

Comment: It is possible to write code that throws an exception although everything is fine but that doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Expections have nothing to do with illegal syntax. Excpetions are used in cases, where an error happens that can't be known about when the code is written or compiled, one example would be that there is no more memory available.

For languages which are compiled (e.g. Java) Expections are thrown while the program runs. On the contrary, syntax errors are handled by the compiler, at compile-time.

Comment: By this can i say what ever be the type of exceptions it occurs only on run time.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax isn't the only resource for Exceptions. Invalid indexing, Mathematical errors, Connection issues, Db structure incompatibilities do cause Exception too!
Unless you are not handling a spesific type of Exception, the purpose of catching general Exceptions is to manage them. If you are not intented to manage them, you *may not* catch them at all. But whatever the situation is **DO NOT SUPPRESS** Exceptions. If you have to handle some erronous situation use logical locks.

Exceptions are for **exceptional situations** only, and should not be used for data validty. Exceptions are way too much costly for that.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions has nothing to do with syntax errors. An exception is a problem that arises during the execution of a program. An exception can occur for many different reasons.

For example, you can see the exceptions in following reasons:

- Invalid entry data.
- File or DB that needs to be opened cannot be found.
- A network connection has been lost in the middle of communications or the VM has run out of memory.

These exceptions are caused by user error, others by programmer error, and others by physical resources that have failed in some manner.

To make the program work smoother, the program should handle the exceptions properly with logic.

Comment: If Every thing is fine i mean

Comment: Class which i want to find would be present,valid data will be given Even though do we have to put in exception block only

Comment: Exception blocks are necessary, if you want to handle unexpected errors to avoid incorrect application behaviour or application crashes. For example, if you write an network program and you are writing some data over network and if you had got network failure, how will you handle this? So won't you think exception block helpful to handle this?